# JSplumb connect to multiple end points

Tags: javascript, html, jsplumb

I need to draw lines from `d1 to d2` and `d1 to d3` using library `JSplumb`.

With below code works only with single source and single target ponints.

**JS:**

```
 jsPlumb.ready(function(){
  jsPlumb.Defaults.Endpoint = "Blank";
  var container = document.getElementById("cartspace");
  jsPlumb.setContainer(container);

  var endpointOptions = { isSource: true, isTarget: true };
  var d1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint( $('#m1'), { anchor: "LeftMiddle" }, endpointOptions );
  var d2 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint( $('#m2'), { anchor: "LeftMiddle" }, endpointOptions );
  var d3 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint( $('#m3'), { anchor: "LeftMiddle" }, endpointOptions );

  jsPlumb.connect({
    source: d1,
    target: d2,
    connector: [ "Flowchart", { curviness: 1, stub: 10 }, {cssClass:"connectorClass"} ],
    paintStyle:{ lineWidth:2, strokeStyle:'green' }
  });

   jsPlumb.connect({
    source: d1,
    target: d3,
    connector: [ "Flowchart", { curviness: 1, stub: 10 }, {cssClass:"connectorClass"} ],
    paintStyle:{ lineWidth:2, strokeStyle:'green' }

  });

});
```

`Check for code`: https://codepen.io/pvnkk/pen/qQxGvQ?editors=1010

```
**Console error: "could not add connection; source endpoint is full"**
```

How connect for multiple target points.check where am i doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell jsplumb that that specific endpoint can support more than 1 connection :

```
var d1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint( $('#m1'), { anchor: "LeftMiddle" }, endpointOptions );
```

with, for example :

```
let endpointOptions = {
            endpoint: ['Dot', { radius: 7 }],
            paintStyle: { fill: '#somecolor' },
            isSource: true,
            scope: 'green',
            connectorStyle: { stroke: '#somecolor', strokeWidth: 3 },
            connector: ['Bezier', { curviness: 63 } ],
            maxConnections: 30,
            isTarget: false,
            connectorOverlays: [ [ 'Arrow', { location:1 } ] ],
            dropOptions: exampleDropOptions
        };
```

here that endpoint will support up to 30 connections, you can use -1 as infinite number.